# Having a plugin trigger on entries.onSaveEntry if a Lightswitch is turned on

Tags: plugin-development, conditional

Essentially I want the plugin to trigger on `entries.onSaveEntry` which I have working fine at the moment. I want to add a Lightswitch field that will be a condition however. i.e. The plugin will only trigger on save if the Lightswitch entry is turned on.

However I'm having trouble finding use of how to get the status of a field (specifically Lightswitch). Is that data available to be in `$event->params['entry']`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's available in `$event->params['entry']`.

```
$entry = $event->params['entry'];
if ($entry->myLightswitch) {
    // do things
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, it's that easy. I was going about it far more complicated. Thank you.